# Storing over 500 k + images as varbinaryblob on Azure BLOB or CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage

I work on UWP app that downloads images from Azure . Although the size of image in < 2 MB , their number is over 500 k. Currently the images are stored in Azure SQL as varbinary .This is consuming 250 GB on the database instance.We need to move it to non relational data storage that has less latency , consumes less space in storage. Which option here (Azure BLOB or Cosmos DB) fits better.? We download the images from REST API connecting to Azure SQL right now using a unique key and want to follow a similar approach with the new  data storage too .It will be great to hear from someone who have used these repositories to handle large number of Images?

Answer (score 5):

"Better" is a matter of opinion. But consider that images aren't metadata - they're just binary, which tends to be the domain of Azure Storage (blobs). Both SQL Database and Cosmos DB have specific limits, and you may find yourself going beyond those limits trying to store such quantities of binary data.

Further: Once you store binary data (such as images) in SQL DB or Cosmos DB, you have no choice but to programmatically retrieve said content (and be bound by the performance constraints you've set within the database / collection). In contrast, Azure Storage has its own independent scale targets, and objects may be accessed directly (whether public, or private + SAS), and cached via CDN.

Ultimately this will come down to the storage architecture you choose for your app, but hopefully this info helps.

Comment: Also, consider the cost. CosmosDB can get expensive pretty quick so this calculating/estimating upfront.

Comment: @Matt - true but... cost is difficult to estimate without benchmarking. Low-level blob transactions can get costly too, if executed frequently enough, since there is a per-transaction cost (whereas Cosmos DB has RU-based pricing, where you know *exactly* what you'll be paying). This really will vary quite a bit, depending on access frequency.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Storing the images seem to be more structured in the database and the size per image .should not increase beyond 2 MB as we have the compression utilities that compress the images. If we take the blob how do we iterate over the 500 k + keys (ImageIds) and retrieve the selected ones?Can we index and sequence the data in Azure BLOB?

Comment: Blob storage doesn't have indexes. Your database (SQL DB, Cosmos DB, etc) would be your index. That is, store the URL to the blob within your database's records or documents. Search for the content you need, with the metadata you store within your database, and retrieve the URL(s) you need, accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to bare in mind in a not so obvious cost in Cosmos DB, there is currently a minimum of 40RU/s per GB of storage in cosmos, hence if you store a large amount of images then you will find the minimum scaling setting may get pretty high which can get expensive quickly.

As David suggested I would store the files in Blob storage and then the file URL alongside the Ids as key value pairs in Cosmos.  This should make Cosmos quite small, efficient and cheap but still give you access to indexing.